# Looking for a condition to filter an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Im trying to build a common filter module that shows objects based on some checkboxes.  So far I was able to build the color section with help of other stackoverflow members.  It shows desired objects when color checkboxes are checked or unchecked. Now I wanna be able to show desired objects based on their size but I couldn't find any condition for it. read comments in code.

```js
var DATABASE = [
    {id:0, color:'green',  size:'L',   collarType:'regular',  cap:false, sleeves:'short', price: 35,   availability: true},
    {id:1, color:'red',    size:'XL',  collarType:'scoop',    cap:false, sleeves:'long',  price: 40,   availability: false},
    {id:2, color:'blue',   size:'M',   collarType:'turtle',   cap:false, sleeves:'3/4',   price: 45,   availability: true},
    {id:3, color:'red',    size:'XXL', collarType:'scoop',    cap:true,  sleeves:'3/4',   price: 25,   availability: false},
    {id:4, color:'red',    size:'L',   collarType:'regular',  cap:true,  sleeves:'short', price: 40,   availability: true},
    {id:5, color:'green',  size:'S',   collarType:'regular',  cap:false, sleeves:'short', price: 70,   availability: false},
    {id:6, color:'yellow', size:'L',   collarType:'v-neck',   cap:true,  sleeves:'short', price: 25,   availability: true}
];
var selection = DATABASE;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const mainContent = document.querySelector('main');

  // COLOR CHECKBOXES
  const chbBlueColor = document.querySelector('#blue-color-filter');
  const chbRedColor = document.querySelector('#red-color-filter');
  const chbGreenColor = document.querySelector('#green-color-filter');
  const chbYellowColor = document.querySelector('#yellow-color-filter');

  // SIZE CHECKBOXES
  const chbXxlSize = document.querySelector('#size-xxl');

  function applyFilter() {

    function filterFn(obj) {
      return (chbBlueColor.checked || obj.color !== "blue") &&
        (chbRedColor.checked || obj.color !== "red") &&
        (chbGreenColor.checked || obj.color !== "green") &&
        (chbYellowColor.checked || obj.color !== "yellow")
        // if 2XL checkbox is checked and no other checkboxes are checked, show all available objects that has a size property = XXL
        // if some other checkboxes are already checked, show objects that has a size property = XXL based on those checked items
    }

    selection = DATABASE.filter(filterFn);

    mainContent.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selection);

  }


  // COLOR EVENT LISTENERS
  chbBlueColor.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
  chbRedColor.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
  chbGreenColor.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
  chbYellowColor.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);

  // SIZE EVENT LISTENERS
  chbXxlSize.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
});
```

```css
section > div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}
H4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
label {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="color-filter">
      <H4>COLOR</H4>
      <input type="checkbox" id="all-colors">
      <label for="all-colors">All</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="blue-color-filter">
      <label for="blue-color-filter">Blue</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="red-color-filter">
      <label for="red-color-filter">Red</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="green-color-filter">
      <label for="green-color-filter">Green</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="yellow-color-filter">
      <label for="yellow-color-filter">Yellow</label>
    </div>

    <div class="size-filter">
      <H4>SIZE</H4>
      <input type="checkbox" id="all-sizes">
      <label for="all-sizes">All</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="size-xxl">
      <label for="size-xxl">2XL</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="size-xl">
      <label for="size-xl">XL</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="size-l">
      <label for="size-l">L</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="size-m">
      <label for="size-m">M</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="size-s">
      <label for="size-s">S</label>
    </div>

    <div class="collar-and-cap-filter">
      <div class="collar-filter">
        <h4>COLLAR</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" id="all-collars">
        <label for="all-collars">All</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collar-regular">
        <label for="collar-regular">Regular</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collar-scoop">
        <label for="collar-scoop">Scoop</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collar-turtle">
        <label for="collar-turtle">Turtle</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collar-vneck">
        <label for="collar-vneck">V-neck</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cap-filter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="all-caps">
        <label for="all-caps">All</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cap available">
        <label for="cap available">Cap</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cap-unavailable">
        <label for="cap-unavailable">No cap</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="availability-filter">
      <input type="checkbox" id="availability">
      <label for="availability">Only Available Products</label>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to isolate your problem to the bare minimum. If you understand it in it's isolation, only then go back and try to integrate it in it's context.

Comment: As @Jieter wrote, provide only that which is needed to represent the specific issue in full. Also, don't provide the description of your problem in code comments. Lastly, what do you mean when you say you *"I couldn't find any condition"*? Did you try writing one? What was the result?

Comment: So, reading from your post, you are "writing" your app by asking a sequence of questions, so that you don't have to learn anything, and the community can invest its time in designing your application? Even better, that you refer us to read the comments in the code... Can you show what effort you have put in trying to solve it yourself?

Comment: @Icepickle Don't judge me. Im just new to JavaScript world and stackoverflow. I spent a day trying to sove the problem. I couldn't and I posted a question

Comment: there is no <main> tag in your html mark up

Comment: The requirement you put in the code will be counter intuitive: if users do not check any color-checkbox, your current code will not show any record. For them to see an item they need to select a color checkbox, which will show items of that color. But then if they don't and select a size checkbox, you want to show items if they match the size, whatever their color. If they then would also click a color, their result set would be reduced! This is not consistent. Checks should either always limit or always extend the results, but not either way depending on other selections.

Answer (score 0):

If you understood what you did for the color problem, well it's basically the same thing for the rest : I understand that you want a selection that correspond to every option checked.

Well try to adapt the filter that you created for colors, and then apply it to the selection (not the DATABASE), this way, you will filter on size objects that have been filtered on color (so they will match both option).

(You can notice that the order is not important here, except for a very large database : you will try to do some prediction on which option will eliminate the greater amount of object and filter on those options first)

Comment: @Icepickle , even if I read Stack Overflow since a while, i'm pretty new in answering questions... Thanks for this tip !